# App update process

Tags: applications, updates, side-loading

Its not yet clear to me what happens when an app gets updated.

Is the new updated app simply being "installed over" the old one maintaining data and cache from the old one? **What actually happens when an app is updated?**

In searching internet<sup>**1**</sup>, and SE, i found no useful information (I am not asking about how to update using googleplay.

PS: In the comments AndrewT and Firelord actually gave me useful pointers and I feel the informations I was looking for center around the workings of PackageManager and PackageInstaller.

---

<sup>**1:** See e.g. ["how does android update apps"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+android+update+apps), [how does android app-update work](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+android+app-update+work), [android app-update process explained](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+app-update+process+explained)</sup>

Comment: I don't think that last statement is well-adhered. Many apps distributed through Google Play have other avenues of distribution. Just think 'Monument Valley', which their own developers say is highly pirated to the tune of 90%. If you just Google it, you'll find dozens of distribution points. [Google query](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=Monument+Valley+apk&oq=Monument+Valley+apk&gs_l=serp.3..0i131j0l9.76954.83473.0.83849.19.11.0.8.8.0.133.743.9j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.18.798.Zp48O9mQc5E)

Comment: It was just an example but I do not want that mentioning it would bog down the answers, so I edited that part out. My question is not about google or other avenues of distribution, it's limited to the update process proper. Wbogacz comment refers to me mentioning that "*apps distributed using GooglePlay cannot be updated in any other way than through GooglePlay according to the Developer Policies*" in the question before i edited it

Comment: `pm install -r FILE`. Whatever that command would do is what technically happens in the background during an app update.

Comment: Can you provide link to the Developer Policies? I think it's the case for developer *to not update their apps outside from Play Store* (e.g. push/forced update from other sites.. probably for security reason), because AFAIK, I could update any apps using their APK (as long as it's using the same certificate)

Comment: @AndrewT. , it is for security reasons, I dont have a direct link to it but it refers to this line in the policies "An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play’s update mechanism". Again, that came out because of an hypothetical scenario and I edited it out because it attracts comments that are not related to my question.

Comment: [I found the article when searching that statement](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/04/google-bans-self-updating-android-apps-possibly-including-facebooks/), but never mind if it's unrelated. I'm not sure how to limit the scope on answer this question: yes, an update will overwrite the "binary" of the app (APK file) while retaining the data/cache. However, there are requirements before it can be updated, such as "app version must be higher/same than current installed", "must use the same certificate", etc. More than that, I can't explain the detail.

Comment: @Izzy, unfortunately, not knowing how it worked, i had no idea how long an answer telling me what i needed would have been. Now that I'm finally homing on the right information Im realizing it will take me quite a bit to learn it. At this point Im considering deleting the question and if i were to ask in programming the answers would be way beyond what i can understand at the moment.

Comment: Actually, I think provided a good answer is given, this "page" would be quite a very useful one. If I weren't so busy currently I'd started an answer, but at the moment it would be a very incomplete one – and I needed to do some research to give my wording some backing (e.g. link to authoritative resources confirming what I write). I don't think you should delete it. Some "rephrasing" might be a good idea (your addition sounds a bit accusing ;) – but per se it is a good question.

Comment: I think the core is in the lines between [10260 to 10350](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r36/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#10260). There are also preliminary preparations done in the beginning but the linked one is the core I believe.

Comment: Incidentally, sideloading an app already existent in one of my devices I got a message asking if I wanted to apply it as upgrade, I never seen that message before or found this behavior described in any article describing how to sideload an app

Comment: @Firelord, thanks, I think I will need some time to digest that one.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note that Android apps don't get installed in the same way as on Windows or on GNU/Linux systems. The app runs entirely from the APK file. Installing an app for the first time includes the following steps:

1. Download the APK to the storage. All apps' APK files get downloaded to the same location.
2. Create a user ID for the new app. Each app in Android runs in its own Linux user ID. This is for security, and is how the permissions system works.
3. Create a data dir for the new app. This is initially empty.
4. Add the app to the phone's database of installed apps. This database includes the name (package ID) of the app, the path to the APK file, the user ID, amongst other things.

That's all it takes. So after that, it's pretty easy to see how to upgrade it:

1. Download the new APK file. This is a new file in the same location as all the other APK files.
2. Check that the old APK can be upgraded to the new APK. It checks that they were both signed by the same key, to avoid data theft, and that the new APK is not an older version, and a few other settings from the app's manifsest. If any of the checks fail so the old APK can't be upgraded to the new APK, the upgrade stops with an error at this point.
3. Stop the old version of the app cleanly.
4. Check for changes to the app (such as new permissions) and update the app's user ID accordingly. Update the database of installed apps to point to the new APK file (and with other data about the new app).
5. Delete the old APK file.

The upgrade process doesn't even have to look at the data directory. It's up to the app to change its data if the new version uses a different format or whatever. (This also means that it's up to the app what old versions can be updated cleanly without losing data.)

The process works the same way whether you're upgrading the app through Google Play, or some other app store, or by clicking on the APK file, or using `adb install`. Whichever front-end you use, it goes through the same package manager. The only difference is that if you use an app store, it probably also keeps its own record of what versions are installed, both to help the app developer understand their user base, and so it can check for future updates.

Comment: "It's up to the app to change its data if the new version uses a different format or whatever" Does that mean that if I have, lets say, version 1 and intend to upgrade directly to version 7 the upgrade might fail if the data of version1 are retained but there has been a change in format in version3 and the newest version has no instructions to change the data format? Or any version after the change will likely be able to upgrade directly from a very old one?

Comment: @ErikvanDoren It's up to the app author. It's possible that if you skip a lot of versions, you might hit a case the author hasn't tested, and the app then won't work properly unless you clear its data (or it might clear the data itself, if it's especially badly written). I'd expect most app authors to handle it properly, though.

Comment: Important detail missing: signature check :) On update, this would be the step *before* stopping the old version. If signatures don't match, the update process would be cancelled at this point.